# Is it possible to get .animate to work on each element using .each?

Tags: jquery, each

as part of an upgrade to my site, I am creating my own image scroller for the bottom of the page. the user clicks the left arrow to scroll through the images by making them all move to the left and same for the right.
I understand how to use .each to effect a list of items and what not, however i cant get it to work with the .animate jquery.
Can anyone shed some light on this please?
my javascript as it stands at the moment:

```
$('#rightButton').click(function()
{
    $('.galleryItem').each( function( index ) 
    {
            $(this).animate({left:"+=100px"},500);
    }); 
});
```

Here is the jsFiddle for it:
http://jsfiddle.net/vLSD3/

Comment: Where's the rest of your code?  Could you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: yeh sure I just made a jsFiddle to look at: http://jsfiddle.net/vLSD3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the element inside of each for animate. `this` is the wrong context.

```
$('#rightButton').click(function()
{
 $('.galleryItem').each( function( index, element ) 
 {
    if ($(element).offset().left < 0) 
    {
        $(element).animate({left:"+=100px"},500);
    }
 }); 
});
```

Here is a very simple demo in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ruuj/

Comment: Thanks Travis J, I found the issue, was more well entirely to do with my CSS, well my positioning, but thanks, I wouldn't have noticed it without your sample :D